# Unclear on steps of LDA?

Tags: classification, discriminant-analysis

I'm trying to understand the steps behind linear discriminant analysis (LDA) in a simple way, but I'm confused on how a few of them connect. Here is what I've got:

1. Break the data apart into groups by class (ex: class1, class2)
2. Calculate the means, covariance matrices, and class probabilities for each group
3. Using the above, calculate the pooled covariance matrix
4. Using the above, calculate the beta values
5. For new observations, use the formula shown below to classify the new observation

Now my first question is - are those the right steps, or am I missing something? And my second question is how does does the formula for Z = B1x1 + B2x2 + .. + BnXn come into place? I know it creates the line on the plot, but how is that used? And what is the purpose of the scoring function?

I've watched a number of YouTube videos and looked at some PDFs online, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a lot of well-answered questions about LDA on this site. So, just browse through topics tagged `discriminant-analysis`. Among the answers presenting LDA with k classes as two-step procedure (extract discriminants, then classify) and with all the necessary formulas, and an example in steps, please see a series of my answers.